Length measurement in FabricJs same as Acrobat reader use
I need to make custom lenght-measurement object in Fabricjs and Angular same as Acrobat reader use. Also I need to keep functionality how length is measured in Acrobat for small distances. Additionally I need to adjust it if length is too small arrows need to be from outside.
Here is my approach but missing initial functionality for measurement. It directly draw Line with arrows. And I need to update it to the Acrobat reader approach.

Three phases: Fritst click -> start point, Second click -> end point,
Third click -> show arrow

<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/68uo9dhz/">JSFiddle demo</a>

I want expected result like Acrobat:

Any suggestion how to do this?

Solution for bad rendering is add strokeWidth property.
